# Getting undesired result while merging two BST

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

The problem is to merge two binary tree, i tried my approach it is giving correct answer in dry run but when I coded it's just printing BST of tree1 and tree2 it's not merging the value...

```
/*
TODO: MERGE TWO BST
*/



#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class BST
{
public:
    int data;
    BST *left;
    BST *right;
    BST(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

BST *insert(BST *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new BST(data);
        return root;
    }
    if (data > root->data)
    {
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}

// step1:method to  store inorder traversal of tree to array
void inorder(BST *root, vector<int> &v)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    inorder(root->left, v);
    v.push_back(root->data);
    inorder(root->right, v);
}

vector<int> mergeArray(vector<int> &vec1, vector<int> &vec2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    // an array to store merged of both and it's size is equal to sum to arr1 and arr2
    vector<int> ans(vec1.size() + vec2.size());
    // loop to array untile all the element is traverse in both
    while (i < vec1.size() && j < vec2.size())
    {
        if (vec1[i] < vec2[j])
        {
            ans[k++] = vec1[i];
            // ans.push_back(vec1[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            ans[k++] = vec2[j];
            // ans.push_back(vec2[j]);
            j++;
        }
        // if any of the element has lower size then traverse another until it is fully traversed
        while (i < vec1.size())
        {
            ans[k++] = vec1[i];
            i++;
        }
        while (j < vec2.size())
        {
            ans[k++] = vec2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
// step 3: method to create BST
BST *inorderToBST(int start, int end, vector<int> &v)
{
    if (start > end)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    BST *root = new BST(v[mid]);

    root->left = inorderToBST(start, mid - 1, v);
    root->right = inorderToBST(mid + 1, end, v);
    return root;
}

// TODO: master method
BST *mergeTwoBST(BST *root1, BST *root2)
{
    vector<int> tree1, tree2;
    // step: store inorder of both tree
    inorder(root1, tree1);
    inorder(root2, tree2);
    // merge both vector
    vector<int> mergedArray = mergeArray(tree1, tree2);
    int start = 0;
    int end = mergedArray.size();
    return inorderToBST(start, end, mergedArray);
}

void printInorder(BST *root)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        return;
    }
    printInorder(root->left);
    cout << root->data << " ";
    printInorder(root->right);
}

int main()
{
    BST *root1 = NULL;
    root1 = insert(root1, 100);
    insert(root1, 50);
    insert(root1, 300);
    insert(root1, 20);
    insert(root1, 70);

    BST *root2 = NULL;
    root2 = insert(root2, 80);
    insert(root2, 40);
    insert(root2, 120);
    // merge
    // cout << "Inorder of Tree 1: ";
    // printInorder(root1);
    // cout << endl
    //      << "Inorder of Tree 2: ";
    // printInorder(root2);
    BST *mergedTree = mergeTwoBST(root1, root2);
    cout << endl
         << "Inorder of merged Array : " << endl;
    printInorder(mergedTree);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is to merge two binary tree, i tried my approach it is giving correct answer in dry run but when I coded it's just printing BST of tree1 and tree2 it's not merging the value...

Please suggest me the correction...

Comment: OT: The macro `NULL` is for backward compatibility with C. In C++ you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: Regarding your problem, have you tried creating the merged vector using simple iterators? Like `std::vector<int> ans(vec1.begin(), vec1.end()); ans.insert(ans.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end());`? If you want it sorted then just `std::sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());` after that?

Comment: As for your current code, the two nested `while` loops in your `mergeArray` function should probably not be nested inside the main loop. You might want to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of that function. Or some very real debugging using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the merging loop,

```
if (vec1[i] < vec2[j])
{
    ans[k++] = vec1[i];
    // ans.push_back(vec1[i]);
    i++;
}
else
{
    ans[k++] = vec2[j];
    // ans.push_back(vec2[j]);
    j++;
}
// if any of the element has lower size then traverse another until it is fully traversed
while (i < vec1.size())
{
    ans[k++] = vec1[i];
    i++;
}
while (j < vec2.size())
{
    ans[k++] = vec2[j];
    j++;
}
```

puts the smallest value in `ans[0]`, then it copies all of `vec1` into `ans`, then it copies all of `vec2` into `ans`.
Then the loop ends, because you have reached the end of both vectors in the first iteration.

You need to finish the "neither vector has reached the end" loop *before* the other loops.

```
// Merge until we reach the end of at least one of the vectors.
while (i < vec1.size() && j < vec2.size())
{
    if (vec1[i] < vec2[j])
    {
        ans[k++] = vec1[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        ans[k++] = vec2[j];
        j++;
    }
}
// If there is anything left in one of the vectors, copy it.  
// Note that we know that at most one of the loop conditions can be true.
while (i < vec1.size())
{
    ans[k++] = vec1[i];
    i++;
}
while (j < vec2.size())
{
    ans[k++] = vec2[j];
    j++;
}
```